# How can I reduce references to show only subsection numbers?

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, counters, assoccnt

I use `cleveref` package to format a special type of labels.
Can I also use a special counter or counter formatting sequence
in `\cref`. 
This is my example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{assoccnt}
\makeatletter
  \crefname{ap}{package}{packages}
  \Crefname{ap}{Package}{Packages}
  \creflabelformat{ap}{AP~#2#1#3}
  \crefformat{ap}{AP~#2#1#3}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \newcounter{ap}{}
  \DeclareAssociatedCounters{subsection}{ap}
  \counterwithout{ap}{section}

  \section{ some section  }
  \section{ special section on packages  }
  \setcounter{ap}{0}

      Here we describe \cref{sec:ap-one,sec:ap-two,sec:ap-three}  ....
      this will be presented in \cref{sec:ap-one,sec:ap-two} and 
      finally in \cref{sec:ap-three}we describe ....

    Preferably this should look like this:

      Here we describe package AP 1 to AP 3  .... 
      this will be presented in packages AP 1 and AP 2 and 
      finally in package AP 3 we describe ....

    but currently it looks like this:

      Here we describe package AP 2.1 to AP 2.3  .... 
      this will be presented in packages AP 2.1 and AP 2.2 and 
      finally in package AP 2.3 we describe ....

   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: first }
   \label[ap]{sec:ap-one}
     bla bla bla
     Here we describe  ... 
     which will be used in \cref{sec:ap-two,sec:ap-three}  ....

   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: second }
   \label[ap]{sec:ap-two}
     bla bla bla
     we described in \cref{sec:ap-one}  .... 
     follow in \cref{sec:ap-three}

     ap counter is \arabic{ap} or \theap.

     subsection counter is \arabic{subsection} 
     and ``thesection'' is \thesubsection.


   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: three }
   \label[ap]{sec:ap-three}
     bla bla bla
     we described in \cref{sec:ap-one,sec:ap-two}  


  \section*{Appendix}
     The table of contents is fine as is 
  \tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: What kind of special counter are you trying to create? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Alenanno: He uses a special associated counter, by application of `assoccnt`, a package written by a bloke who wrote a comment here ;-)

Comment: `\newcounter{ap}{}` is wrong. Since `ap` is not in the reset list of `section` (it's an associated counter), `counterwithout{ap}{section}` is not necessary. `cleveref` should  be the last package and `makeatletter...\makeatother`is not necessary there!

Comment: @Christian  I just use \newcounter{ap}  and ommit counterwithout, but it makes no difference to the output. What I want is, to use \theap instead of \thesubsection to be displayed by \cref, or something similar.

Comment: @Gerald, yes,I suspect that the `\cref` formats are wrongly defined. My `assoccnt` package (please use `xassoccnt`, the newer,better one) works with `cleveref` normally

Comment: @Gerald: The problem is that labelling associated counters is not in the package design, but because this would lead to wrong references.

Comment: I'll try to fix this in the afternoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: As of version 1.2. of `xassoccnt` supports the experimental feature of labels to associated counters. 
See the example for version 1.2 (and later) below**

Amongst some 'wrong' usage of `\newcounter` etc. and the fact, that `cleveref` should be the last package to be included, the main cause that the wrong output is used has its origins in the fact `\label[ap]{...}` assuming, that the `ap` counter has been used with `\refstepcounter`, but this is not true.

I designed the `assoccnt` package (and its successor `xassoccnt`) to have associated counters which are stepped too when the master counter is stepped (`subsection` here), but declined to apply this feature for `\refstepcounter` too, since this would be ambiguous -- the associated counters would be stepped, but each one would set the `\@currentlabel` entry, thereby overwritting the master counter `label`. Since an associated counter has a totally different value than its master counter the `\label` command would write a wrong counter and reference value to the `.aux` file.

Now, `\refstepcounter` would use the subsection value and this is still in the `2.1` format, so `\label[ap]{...}` writes some `{2.1}` value as reference to the `.aux` file.

The solution is to use a different label command, which generates a fake label `\@currentlabel` suitable for `cref` and sets the values then.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\newcounter{ap}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{subsection}{ap}
\counterwithout{ap}{section}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
% Generate a fake label
\newcommand{\labelap}[2][ap]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\cref@result{2}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \label[ap]{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\crefname{ap}{package}{packages}
\Crefname{ap}{Package}{Packages}
\creflabelformat{ap}{AP~#2#1#3}
\crefformat{ap}{AP~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}


  \section{ some section  }
  \section{ special section on packages  }
  \setcounter{ap}{0}

      Here we describe \cref{sec:ap-one,sec:ap-two,sec:ap-three}  ....
      this will be presented in \cref{sec:ap-one,sec:ap-two} and 
      finally in \cref{sec:ap-three}we describe ....

    Preferably this should look like this:

      Here we describe package AP 1 to AP 3  .... 
      this will be presented in packages AP 1 and AP 2 and 
      finally in package AP 3 we describe ....

    but currently it looks like this:

      Here we describe package AP 2.1 to AP 2.3  .... 
      this will be presented in packages AP 2.1 and AP 2.2 and 
      finally in package AP 2.3 we describe ....

   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: first }
   \labelap{sec:ap-one}
     bla bla bla
     Here we describe  ... 
     which will be used in \cref{sec:ap-two,sec:ap-three}  ....

   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: second }
   \labelap{sec:ap-two}
     bla bla bla
     we described in \cref{sec:ap-one}  .... 
     follow in \cref{sec:ap-three}

     ap counter is \arabic{ap} or \theap.

     subsection counter is \arabic{subsection} 
     and ``thesection'' is \thesubsection.


   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: three }
   \labelap{sec:ap-three}
     bla bla bla
     we described in \cref{sec:ap-one,sec:ap-two}  


  \section*{Appendix}
     The table of contents is fine as is 
  \tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

**Version 1.2 style of solution**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\NewDocumentCounter{ap, apother}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{subsection}{ap, apother}

\counterwithout{ap}{section}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{ap}{package}{packages}
\Crefname{ap}{Package}{Packages}
\creflabelformat{ap}{AP~#2#1#3}
\crefformat{ap}{AP~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

See \cref{foosection}

  \section{ some section  } \label{foosection}
  \section{ special section on packages  }
  \setcounter{ap}{0}

      Here we describe \cref{ap::ap-one,ap::ap-two,ap::ap-three}  ....
      this will be presented in \cref{ap::ap-one,ap::ap-two} and 
      finally in \cref{ap::ap-three} we describe ....

    Preferably this should look like this:

      Here we describe package AP 1 to AP 3  .... 
      this will be presented in packages AP 1 and AP 2 and 
      finally in package AP 3 we describe ....

    but currently it looks like this:

      Here we describe package AP 2.1 to AP 2.3  .... 
      this will be presented in packages AP 2.1 and AP 2.2 and 
      finally in package AP 2.3 we describe ....

   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: first } \label{ap-one}
     bla bla bla
     Here we describe  ... 
     which will be used in \cref{ap::ap-two,ap::ap-three}  ....


   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: second }
   \label{ap-two}
     bla bla bla
     we described in \cref{ap::ap-one}  .... 
     follow in \cref{ap::ap-three}

     ap counter is \arabic{ap} or \theap.

     subsection counter is \arabic{subsection} 
     and ``thesection'' is \thesubsection.


   \subsection{AP~\arabic{ap}: three }
   \label{ap-three}
     bla bla bla
     we described in \cref{ap::ap-three,ap::ap-two} but look at \ref{ap-three}  


  \section*{Appendix}
     The table of contents is fine as is 
  \tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer works greatly using the `assoccnt` package, but I get an error `Undefined control sequence \str_const:Nn` from xassoccnt.sty:36

Comment: @Gerald: You need the newest `expl3` version -- `str_const:Nn` was added about three months ago --> it will work with `xassoccnt` too then